# Java monitoring activemq but without polling the queue

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I need to program something that monitors an activemq queue in java. This means I need to log when a message is enqueued on the queue and when a message is dequeued. My program must not send messages or receives messages, it only needs to log.

I found out to push messages and receive messages but this is not what I want to do, just log if an external process puts messages on or off the queue.

To make it more clear I made a drawing
[image]

I use apache camel to make the integration,
my routebuilder looks like

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
        Processor queueProcessor = new QueueProcessor();

        from("activemq:queue:KBC").process(queueProcessor);
    }
```

it calls the folowwing processor

```
@Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Trax_EventDao dao = new Trax_EventDao();
        dao.insert(new Trax_Event("Queue",exchange.getExchangeId(),"UP","KBC", new Time(new Date().getTime())));
    }
```

The dao handles a database connection and makes an insert of a record

The actual problem is that  when I push a message on the queue and the program runs, the message got logged which is okay, but it also get polled immediately, which is not okay.
How can I make the insert without the message being polled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was writing an own runner class, which uses a queuebrowser.

What I wanted to do with this class is

1. Make a connection with avtivemq and start it
2. Make an endless loop, which controls the queue specified. I have a list of the items on the queue. At every loop I check this
3. if the list is bigger than the size of the queue, there are items dequeued. This means I need to loop this and check which items are dequeued.
   Otherwhise I loop the enumeration of the queue and add elements to the list if they don't exist yet

   ```
   package queueFeed;

   import dao.ProcmonDao;
   import dao.EventDao;
   import domain.Event;
   import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
   import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;

   import javax.jms.*;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Time;
   import java.util.*;

   public class QueueRunner {
       private ProcmonDao dao;
       private Connection connection;
       private String queueName;

       public QueueRunner() throws SQLException {
           dao = new EventDao();
       }

   public void setConnection(String username, String password, String url) throws JMSException {
       ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(username, password, url);
       connection = factory.createConnection();
   }

   public void run() throws Exception {
       Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
       QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(new ActiveMQQueue(queueName));

       List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
       int queueSize = 0;
       int counter = 0;
       connection.start();

       while (true) {
           Enumeration enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
           if (queueSize < ids.size()) {
               while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                   Message message = (Message) enumeration.nextElement();
                   ids.remove(message.getJMSMessageID());
                   counter++;
               }

               if (ids.size() > 0 && ids.size() > 0) {
                   Iterator<String> iterator = ids.iterator();
                   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                       String messageId = iterator.next();
                       dao.insert(new Event("Queue", messageId, "UP", browser.getQueue().getQueueName(), new Time(new Date().getTime())));
                       iterator.remove();
                   }
               }

               queueSize = counter;
               counter = 0;
           } else {

               while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                   counter++;
                   Message message = (Message) enumeration.nextElement();
                   String id = message.getJMSMessageID();
                   if (!ids.contains(id)) {
                       ids.add(id);
                       dao.insert(new Event("Queue", id, "UP", browser.getQueue().getQueueName(), new Time(new Date().getTime())));
                   }
               }
               queueSize = counter;
               counter = 0;
           }
       }
   }

   public void setQueueName(String queueName) {
       this.queueName = queueName;
   }

   public String getQueueName() {
       return this.queueName;
   }
   ```

   }

This works not perfect yet. I think there is a small logical issue in it.

Answer (score 3):

you can use ActiveMQ Advisory Messages to monitor queue activity...

see http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html